# It is best to generate the html content through php classes?

Tags: php, html

I've been playing around in the Web Development field for 2 years now and I am pretty proud when it comes to my progress as a programmer looking back at my humble beggining. This is not very relevant but I've wanted to back up my question with some background story. What it comes to my interest during a conversation with a friend was how to best structure your code when it comes to a website so it wil be very scalable for further modifications using an oop aproach. He suggested at the end of the discusion to use php classes to generate the html content. I personally use it like this only when the php helps me to retrieve something server-side related. I use HTML, CSS and JavaScript (in that order) as much as possible before calling in PHP. That's how it should work, in my opinion, especially when you have to work on a presentation website for example. What's intrigue me thinking about my friend proposal is that I structure my code that way using php clases to echo html content parts like header, menu, forms, slideshows, footer etc. will indeed scale my code way better and help my programming skills progress. I should end up with an index.php that returns objects of the respective classes creating that way the desired html content. This is how I image things working and I am asking you to help me reach a decision. I have some upcoming free time available and I want to invest it in becoming a better web developer.

Comment: Sorry, way to much blah to read it all. Please remove all background story and make a brief question. Maybe with some code if necessary.

Comment: From what I'm getting this is an opinion / convention question. I would suggest learning a framework with your free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea for all HTML to be generated this way.

In professional web development you often have front-end developers and designers whose only responsibility is the HTML/CSS/assets and/or JavaScript.  The backend developers, (the ones writing PHP code), are usually responsible for the business logic of the application.

By having PHP generate HTML you are violating separation of concerns principles.   Things will get messy.  It's harder to scale up, and you will lose the benefits of being able to use a HTML editor.

Generating HTML serverside dynamically has uses in very specific circumstances.  It can be done, but just because you can, doesn't mean you should.